# Convert excel spreadsheet into html using vb.net?

Tags: html, vb.net, xls

I would like to see some code/tutorials on reading an excel spreadsheet (a calender) into VB.NET. I'm pretty much okay from there. I want to convert it to an HTML table and output it  into an html file for inclusion on a website.

Where can I find tutorials OR can someone post some code with a desciption to get me startd?

BONUS:

Is there a better way to include a xls file in a webpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an excel reader available on Codeproject [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/ExcelReader.aspx). The article covers the Excel file format layout, and the related material from Sun, in respect to how OpenOffice reads in the Excel spreadsheet.

AFAIK, there is no way to include an xls in a webpage unless you are talking about showing the actual data, it may be possible under IE only, to trigger the end user's Excel application, but IMHO that would be a dangerous assumption as that assumes the user has MS-Office installed.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: not relevant question anymore, but the codeproject seems right, so: Check!